# My code won't run, but i suppose that it's because I lack experience in html/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, math

I am writing up a simple webpage that'll perform numerical integration on basic elementary functions (sin, cos, exp..etc). This web page should contain at least the rectangle rule, midpoint rule and trapezoidal rule.

The code I have written thus far work up until the rectangle rule but, when I execute the command to run the code for the midpoint rule, I get no output where I believe I should get output.

I suspect that this may be due to the fact that I don't quite understand the intimate relationship between html and js.

```js
function getFunction(str, x) {
  nameObj = {
    "sin": 0,
    "cos": 1,
    "exp": 2
  };
  var fAtx = [Math.sin(x), Math.cos(x), Math.exp(x)];
  return fAtx[nameObj[str]];
}

//rectangle rule 
function rectangle_rule() {
  var limit_a = document.getElementById("a_rect").value;
  var limit_b = document.getElementById("b_rect").value;
  var limit_diff = limit_b - limit_a;
  var functionInput = document.getElementById("funcRectangle").value;
  var rect_rule = limit_diff * getFunction(functionInput, limit_a);
  document.getElementById("answerRectangle").value = rect_rule;
  return rect_rule;

}

//midpoint rule rule 
function midpointRule() {
  var limit_a = document.getElementById("a_mid").value;
  var limit_b = document.getElementById("b_mid").value;
  var functionInput = document.getElementById("funcMidpoint").value;
  var limit_diff = limit_b - limit_a;
  var x_c = limit_a + limit_b / 2;
  var midpoint_rule = limit_diff * getFunction(functionInput, x_c);
  document.getElementById("answerMidpoint").value = midpoint_rule;
  //  return midpoint_rule;
}
```

```css
.main {
  border: 15px solid rgb(199, 124, 62);
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.heading1 {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.body {
  background-color: khaki;
}

.rectangle {
  width: fit-content;
  height: 200px;
}

.math {
  font-size: 35px;
}

.Midpoint {
  width: fit-content;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>

<div class="main">
  <h1 class="heading1">Numerical Integration</h1>
</div>
<div>
  <p>This is a simple numerical integration calculator. Please choose from the following functions (in the exact same form they are written here):<br> sin, cos, exp.
  </p>
  <p>
    More functionality will be added soon...
  </p>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="#rectangle_rule">The Rectangle Rule</a><br><br>
      <li><a href="#midpoint_rule">The Midpoint Rule</a></li><br>
      <li>The Trapezoidal Rule</li><br>
      <li>Simpson's Rule</li><br>
  </ul>
</div>
<!--Rectangle rule start---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
<div class="rectangle" id="rectangle_rule">
  <table>
    <tr style="height: 15%;">Rectangle Rule<br></tr>
    <tr>
      <!--mathml for rectangle rule start---------------------------------------------------------->
      <math displaystyle="true" class="math">
                                <mrow>
                                    <msubsup>
                                        <mi>&int;</mi>
                                        <mn>a</mn>
                                        <mn>b</mn>
                                    </msubsup>
                                    <mi>f</mi>
                                    <mfenced> <mi>x</mi> </mfenced>
                                    <mi>dx</mi>
                                </mrow>
                                <mrow>
                                    <mo>&asymp;</mo>
                                    <mrow>
                                        <mfenced separators="">
                                            <mi>b</mi>
                                            <mo>-</mo>
                                            <mi>a</mi>
                                        </mfenced>
                                    </mrow>
                                    <mi>f</mi>
                                    <mfenced><mi>a</mi></mfenced>   
                                </mrow>
                            </math>
      <!--mathml for rectangle rule end-------------------------------------------------------------->
      <td>

        Function:
        <input type="text" id="funcRectangle" placeholder="sin,cos,exp"> Limit a:
        <input type="text" id="a_rect" style="width: 15%;"> Limit b:
        <input type="text" id="b_rect" style="width: 15%;"><br>
        <input type="button" value="Compute Integral" onclick="rectangle_rule()">
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="answerRectangle" readonly="readonly" style="font-size: 20px;">

      </td>
    </tr>
    <br>
  </table>

</div>
<!--Rectangle rule end------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->

<!--Midpoint Rule start-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
<div class="midpoint" id="midpoint_rule">
  <table>
    <tr style="height: 15%;">Midpoint Rule<br></tr>
    <tr>
      <!--mathml for midpoint rule start---------------------------------------------------------->
      <math displaystyle="true" class="math">
                        <mrow>
                            <msubsup>
                                <mi>&int;</mi>
                                <mn>a</mn>
                                <mn>b</mn>
                            </msubsup>
                            <mi>f</mi>
                            <mfenced> <mi>x</mi> </mfenced>
                            <mi>dx</mi>
                        </mrow>
                        <mrow>
                            <mo>&asymp;</mo>
                            <mrow>
                                <mfenced separators="">
                                    <mi>b</mi>
                                    <mo>-</mo>
                                    <mi>a</mi>
                                </mfenced>
                            </mrow>
                            <mi>f</mi>
                            <mfenced>
                                <mfrac>
                                    <mi>a+b</mi>
                                    <mi>2</mi>
                                </mfrac>
                            </mfenced>   
                        </mrow>
                    </math>
      <!--mathml for midpoint rule end-------------------------------------------------------------->

      <!--User input section start------------------------------------------------------------------------->
      <td> Function:
        <input type="text" id="funcMidpoint" placeholder="sin,cos,exp"> Limit a:
        <input type="text" id="a_mid" style="width: 15%;"> Limit b:
        <input type="text" id="b_mid" style="width: 15%;"><br>
        <input type="button" value="Compute Integral" onclick="midpoint_rule()"><br><br>
        <input type="text" id="answerMidpoint" readonly="readonly" style="font-size: 20px;">
      </td>
      <!--User input section end--------------------------------------------------------------------->
    </tr>
    <br>
  </table>
</div>
```

When I input data in the required field for the midpoint rule I get absolutely no output. I do get output from the rectangle rule that is consistent with code written in python for the same exact function (the rectangle rule).

Comment: Checked the console for errors? I popped your code into a stack snippet and the first thing I see is `WARNING: cdn.mathjax.org has been retired. Check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.`

Comment: `midpoint_rule` is not a function. you are calling that instead of `midpointRule`  in the button's `onclick`

Comment: use same naming convention for all of your functions it will help in reducing these errors.

Comment: @j08691 welp! Where do you get that error? the mathml seems to be working fine on my browser (chrome and firefox). Again I'm completely new (been at it for less than a week). I will have to check that out i guess. I would like to display mathematical objects on my page though... anyways, thank you!

Comment: Look at the developer console.

Comment: @Akhilesh is there a specific naming convention in javascript like there is for python?

Comment: @SoufianeHassou ah, a simple naming error geez. Thank you!

Comment: mostly Variable and function names written as camelCase. you can have a look at this link https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_conventions.asp

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/

Answer (score 1):

Try calling midpointRule onclick instead  and add a console.log in the function to see it it's even firing in the first place.